# .htaccess exact url redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two web-sites:
**example.com** and 
**yyy.com**

They both have similar web apps, but on different servers. I want to make Apache redirect all path requests to **example.com** exactly the same way to **yyy.com**.

For example:

```
1. Request:     example.com/pages/contacts
   Redirects to yyy.com/pages/contacts
2. Request:     example.com/search?first_val=45&second_val=45
   Redirects to yyy.com/search?first_val=45&second_val=45
```

So, is there any way to make such `.htaccess` file? And if yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```